# Unsuccessful conversion of byte stream array to bitmap image via socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, bitmap, android-glide

I am sending a screenshot from java server hosted on a machine. The screenshot would be send to an android device through sockets in form of a byte stream array. But the array which I am getting in the android device is not getting converted to bitmap. Below I am attaching the java server code, android code and the logcat.

Here is the java server code for sending the screenshot captured.

socket2 = serverSocket2.accept();
            System.out.println("A client has connected");

```
         Robot robot = new Robot();
         String format = "jpg";
         String fileName = "FullScreenshot." + format;

         Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect); // captured image
            ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\"+fileName));
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(screenFullImage,format,bao);//ye

            byte[] ar=bao.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("Parental block is executed");        
            mainWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket2.getOutputStream()));
            mainWriter.write(java.util.Arrays.toString(ar));
            mainWriter.newLine();
            mainWriter.flush();

         System.out.println("A full screenshot saved!");

         serverSocket2.close();
         socket2.close();
         mainWriter.close();
         Testing t = new Testing();
```

Here is the android code where I am getting the byte stream array.

```
public void PCConnection(final View view) // just for this activity
{
    new Thread()
    {

        public Socket socket;

        public void run()
        {

            try
            {

                Log.i(DebuggString,"Attempting to connect to the server");
                socket = new Socket(hostname,60120);
                Log.i(DebuggString,"Connection established");
                mivScreenShot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivScreenShot);
                //Receive message from the server
                //Message is stored in the br.readLine()
                brr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                img = brr.readLine();
                Log.d("Image", img);//yeh byte[] display karta h
                final ByteArrayInputStream arrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(img.getBytes());
                arrayInputStream.reset();
                this.socket.close();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Glide.with(ParentalControl.this)
                                .load(bitmap)
                                .asBitmap()
                                .into(mivScreenShot);
                    }
                });
                if(bitmap!=null)
                {
                    Log.d(DebuggString,"Bitmap is not null "); // oh ok koi nai
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(DebuggString,"Bitmap is null");
                }





            }
            catch (IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }.start();
}
```

Here I am attaching the logcat screenshot url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGv5g.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mainWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket2.getOutputStream()));
        mainWriter.write(java.util.Arrays.toString(ar));
```

You cannot use writers and strings to send a jpg image as those are for text only. Do away with them. Do away with the ByteOutputStream too as you can just directly compress the bitmap to the outputstream of the socket.

Further check how many bytes you send and how many are received.

That was for the server. Also on the receiving side you cannot use readers and strings.

Comment: i want to just send an image from java server to android client . if you have another alternative it would be also good for me.

Comment: Yes i know what you want and already told you what you should do.

Comment: thanks for it i got it done with FileOuputStream. thanks greenapps